# Why doesn't my Facebook integrated with Android app run on a mobile phone?

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am a newbie in Facebook integration with Android. I have integrated `Facebook` with `Android` in which I have to move on to another activity after successful Facebook login. I tested my app on the emulator and it runs fine. But when I run it on a mobile phone, the Facebook login page appears and I enter the username and password, and next nothing happens. 
My code is as follows:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
private static final String URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=";
private ImageButton buttonLoginLogout;
public static final String PREFS_PRIVATE = "PREFS_PRIVATE";
private Button b;
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
Databasehandler db=new Databasehandler(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    buttonLoginLogout = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }

    updateView();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

}
private void updateView() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final String t1=user.getId();
                final String t2=user.getName();
                 // SharedPreferences myPrefs =getSharedPreferences("myprefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                int count=db.getme();
                if(count==0)
                {
                map.put("uid",t1.toString());
                map.put("name",t2.toString());
                db.insertnewuser(map);
                }
            }
        });


        Intent ik=new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);

        ik.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(ik);


    } else {

        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
        });
    }
}

private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}


private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        updateView();
    }
}
}
```

Error log:

```
         03-31 20:17:09.743: E/chromium(28558): external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:792: [0331/201709:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(792)] handshake failed; returned 0, SSL error code 5, net_error -107
```

Comment: Check for the respons/error of the facebook login

Comment: pls check my error log